# Layout - Tkinter - Grouping buttons together

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new using `Tkinter` and I am making a really easy GUI. Coming from JavaFX background I am finding it a bit confusing because I cannot base my buttons position on the coordinates.

This is my actual code:

```
class MoveRobot(Frame):

grid_counter = 0

def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Control Robot")
    self.master.geometry("400x400")
    self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid(sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.list_box = Listbox(self)
    self.list_box.grid(rowspan=4, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button1 = Button(self, text="UP", command=self.button_up)
    self.button1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button2 = Button(self, text="DOWN", command=self.button_down)
    self.button2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button3 = Button(self, text="LEFT", command=self.button_left)
    self.button3.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button4 = Button(self, text="RIGHT", command=self.button_right)
    self.button4.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button_cancel = Button(self, text="Remove Last", command=self.button_remove_last)
    self.button_cancel.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button_cancel = Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.button_clear)
    self.button_cancel.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.button_compile = Button(self, text="Compile", command=self.button_compile)
    self.button_compile.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

#controller code is removed because unnecessary

def main():
    MoveRobot().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the one below is my GUI created.

[image: GUI built it from the code provided]

However, I cannot manage to stick the button 'UP', 'DOWN', 'LEFT' and 'RIGHT' together. I've tried to look over forums and websites but I could not find a solution. It should be pretty straightforward because it is just a layout problem.

The output I want should be something like this..

[image: GUI wanted]

Anyone is able to help? I hope this question will be beneficial for other people as well since I don't know how to use Tkinter and I can't find a solution over the web.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to restructure your grid slightly...
In this case, your listbox takes up as many rows as the buttons. So the rows' heights will be evenly dispersed over the listbox's height, and the buttons placed evenly along the listbox height. However, if you want your buttons grouped together at the top, the row after the last button has to 'stretch' to account for the extra space.
Maybe this (clumsy) ascii-art will demonstrate...
`---------
|    lb    |   Box 1  (row 1)
|    lb    |   Box 2  (row 2)
|    lb    |   Box 3  (row 3)
|    lb    |   xxxxx  (row 4)
|    lb    |   xxxxx  (still row 4)`
---------
`Other boxes`
The solution is `rowconfigure`!
This will tell tkinter how to expand a row if there is extra space for it to expand into.
This is necessary, because if a row is empty, I believe tkinter automatically assumes that it should not be there, shrinks it to nothing and stretches the others.
In this case, increase your listbox's rowspan by 1, then call `self.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)`.
the 4 is the new (empty!) row you have created, `weight` tells tkinter to expand by one relative unit, which is useful if you have multiple `rowsconfigures` and maybe want to have one expand double as fast.
P.S. you will need to move the other buttons down by 1!

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't make any sense. Giving the listbox an explicit height accomplishes nothing in this case (unless it's set to a really small number). Also, weight does _not_ "tells tkinter to expand by one unit". I don't know what you think a "unit" is in this context, but the weight just tells tkinter how to distribute extra space in a widget.

Comment: You're right @BryanOakley , it does not expand by any specific unit, I was being unclear

Comment: @BryanOakley However, I stand by what I said about the explicit height. Given that the listbox is taller than it needs to be in the layout (see my ascii), tkinter will shrink it unless told how large it must be... There may be other ways of solving this, but this seemed the simplest one to me, and it does work in some tests I've done

Comment: I encourage you to try it. Tkinter will only shrink it to its preferred height, which for a listbox defaults to 10 lines if you don't give an explicit height.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that it defaulted to 10... I guess that's redundant then, although not strictly speaking incorrect

Answer (score 2):

The trick to solving layout problems is to break your UI down into sections, and focus on one section at a time. In your case I see three sections: a listbox on the left, a group of buttons on the right, and a group of buttons at the bottom.

Since you're asking specifically about the buttons on the right, that's the group I'll address in this answer.

In my opinion, the easiest solution is to create a frame for the buttons, and then pack the buttons at the top of the frame:

```
button_frame = Frame(self)
self.button1 = Button(button_frame, ...)
self.button2 = Button(button_frame, ...)
self.button3 = Button(button_frame, ...)
self.button4 = Button(button_frame, ...)

self.button1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
self.button2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
self.button3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
self.button4.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

With that, no matter where you put that frame the buttons will always be at the top. In your case, you can put the listbox and the frame in the same row:

```
    self.list_box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    button_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```